# Using schema annotations in Xforms

Tags: orbeon

(I'm using Orbeon Forms 2019.2.0.201912301747 CE). I have a bunch of XForms for which the schemas are in a JAR file in orbeons "WEB-INF\lib". (I am able to get individual schemas using the "oxf:" protocol).
XML Schema has "annotations/documentation" and "annotations/appInfo" elements (intended for use by the application) and I ***swear*** that in the past I've read how to access these in XForms, but searching online I can no longer find any information about it! I'd like to find out if I can use "appInfo" in the schema to store text presented to the user (xforms alerts or hints), instead of breaking it out into a separate xml file. (The reason being that subsequent versions of the schema might have this text change, and an XSD documenter can pick up this information.)

I remember it being something pretty simple. Is there someone here who does this? Does it work with Orbeon?

Answer (score 0):

The possibility that comes to mind would be to load the XML Schema into an XForms instance. This is possible because the XML Schema is in XML as well. Then you can refer to various parts of the Schema with XPath in labels, hints, etc. You just need, of course, to know the path to those elements in the XML Schema file.

Comment: I did arrive at that solution, and it works. (I found an Orbeon sample that queries the schema instance). However, it's somewhat cumbersome, necessitating really long paths (at least for my schema). I'm still undecided if it has any advantage over just using an XML file, what I was thinking is that it might be good to have this information in the schema for documentation reasons. (I created my own schema as well for the "appInfo" content).

I was hoping there might be an xpath function that could get the path in the schema to the definition of an element/type, but there doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Curious as to why are your paths are long? Do you have an example?

Comment: Well, party because I wanted to try out "standardizing" the appInfo by creating a namespace that could be imported into my schemas. So I had something like "$schemainstance/content//xs:element[name='elname']/xs:annotation/xs:appInfo/xai:xf_info/xai:help" where "xai" is the namespace.

Comment: Just wondering, if the xforms processor has to get the schema info for the referenced field, would it be theoretically possible for an xpath function to get app info for that element? I realize that in many schemas the type would be defined outside of an element, so you could actually have different appinfo for the element and the type. Not sure how many would find this useful.

Comment: We'd have to look at the source of the XML Schema processor to see if that's exposed, but on top of my head I don't know.